# Pocket PC 2003 vs Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, pocketpc

I am considering changing Target device for one of my projects from Pocket PC 2003 Device to Windows Mobile.

I am new to the area however and would like first to explore pros and cons and potential issues I might have.

Finally and if possible, how can I change target device?  I looked in Project Properties->Devices->Target device dropdown and that dropdowns lists only Pocket PC 2003 Devices, no Windows Mobile 5.0 or higher.  However, I am on VS2008 and I know that I can create a brand new project targeting Windows Mobile 5.0, but how to change an old project from Pocket PC 2003 Device to Windows Mobile 5.0?

Much appreciated,

db

Comment: I don't think you can but has been a while for me. these are different templates and platforms/architecture so you cannot quite mix and match but you can port over code with some modification due to the features exposed/unavailable from one platform to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the progr. language you can switch between Target platforms in the Solution Configuration Manager.
There is a column with Platform. There you can click the drop down arrow and select  and then change to any of the installed Windows Mobile SDKs you have installed on your PC.

Comment: Hi Josef,  and thanks for your reply.  I use C# in VS2008 and I figured out that I can just right-click on my project -> Change Target Platform.  My main concern is would Windows Mobile 5.0 or higher project support also Pocket PC 2003 devices.  Thanks

Comment: It depends. If you use any special API or .net lib of WM5, your app will not run on PPC2003.